# Как вызывать функцию FFmpeg main() из Qt

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg

Как можно вызывать функцию из `\fftols\ffmpeg.c` c параметрами

```
> ffmpeg {1} {2} -i {3} {4} {5}, где:

{1} — глобальные параметры
{2} — параметры входного файла
{3} — входящий URL
{4} — параметры выходного файла
{5} — исходящий URL
```

В QtCreator?

Я скачал .zip архив FFmpeg: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg

И поместил данный архив в корень своего тестового проекта на QT где лежит .pro файл, который хочу запустить на android

Переименовал в файле `\fftols\ffmpeg.c` функцию `int main(int argc, char **argv)` на `int ffmpeg_main(int argc, char **argv)` дабы не возникали ошибки с вызовом этой функции

По началу ругалось на отсутствие файла `avconfig.h`

Добавил её собственноручно взяв образец из интернета

```
/* Generated by ffmpeg configure */
#ifndef AVUTIL_AVCONFIG_H
#define AVUTIL_AVCONFIG_H
#define AV_HAVE_BIGENDIAN 0
#define AV_HAVE_FAST_UNALIGNED 0
#endif /* AVUTIL_AVCONFIG_H */
```

В самом .pro файле добавил:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/FFmpeg
```

После этого данный код собрался в Qt для android arm64-v8a c компилятором Android Clang

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

extern "C"
{
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libavutil/opt.h"
#include "libswscale/swscale.h"
#include "libavfilter/avfilter.h"
#include "libavutil/log.h"
#include "libavutil/imgutils.h"
}

// Extermal Functions Declaration
extern "C"
{
// помните, мы переименовали main() функцию в ffmpeg.c в ffmpeg_main() вот здесь она и декларируется
int ffmpeg_main(int argc, char **argv);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    //ffmpeg();
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Но когда я хочу взывать функцию ffmpeg_main()

```
void ffmpeg()
{
    int argc = 5;
            
    char* argv[5] = { "ffmpeg", "-i", "//storage//extSdCard//DCIM//Camera//video.mp4", "-an", "//storage//extSdCard//DCIM//Camera//video_no_audio.mp4"};

    // вызов этой функции с такими аргументами это то же самое, как если бы вы запустили в консоли программу ffmpeg.exe с такими параметрами:
    // > ffmpeg.exe -i "storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/video.mp4" -an "storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/video_no_audio.mp4"
    // параметр -an говорит ffmpeg удалить аудио подток из файла, короче убрать звук и сохранить новый файл в video_no_audio.mp4
    ffmpeg_main(argc, argv);
}
```

Возникает ошибка `undefined reference to "ffmpeg_main"`

Я много раз натыкался, что нужно перед использованием собирать FFmpeg. В моём случае я так понимаю в файлы `.so` для android. Но не понимаю зачем, если все исходники `.c/.h` файлов есть и можно их подключить в проект? Можно ли как-то без предварительной конфигурации FFmpeg обойтись и просто вызвать функцию `ffmpeg_main()` в Qt?

Comment: Ах и да, сам Qt видит функцию `ffmpeg_main(argc, argv);` когда на неё наводишь курсором с нажатым ctrl и при нажатии перебрасывает в файл ffmpeg.c на 4819 строку

Comment: Ваша ошибка говорит о том, что не может найти реализацию функции, что, по описанному и очевидно. С большой вероятностью Вам все таки нужно будет собрать ffmpeg или поискать уже собранный под Вашу платформу.

Comment: *Но не понимаю зачем, если все исходники .c/.h файлов есть и можно их подключить в проект?* - ну так а вы их подключили? :) В вопросе про это не говорится. `INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/FFmpeg` это только позволяет `#include` писать, а где указан нужный файл реализации `ffmpeg.c`?

Comment: Такие библиотеки как FFmpeg нужно компилировать отдельно. Во-первых, это занимает время. Во-вторых, будет генерироваться куча временных и ненужных файлов. В-третих, чтобы сбилдить такие либы, частенько нужно постараться, а уж чтобы автоматизировать сборку из своего проекта... нужно конкретно запариться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге пришлось все таки использовать .so файлы.
На windows, как указано в разных источниках у меня не удалось из скаченных исходников собрать свои .so библиотеки, поэтому я скачал `mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl-4.3.2.aar`
по ссылке https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg/releases/tag/v4.3.2. Открыл данный файл `WinRar` и вытащил все .so файлы из архитектур `armeabi-v7a` и `arm64-v8a` в папке `Jni` подключил эти библиотеки в .pro файл с помощью `LIBS +=\`.
По ссылке https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg/tree/master/src/ffmpeg скачал по новой FFMPEG libav и закинул его в проект. Указал с помошью `INCLUDEPATH +=\` путь куда я его закинул.
Данные файлы `h.\c.` закинул туда же где лежат остальные файлы https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg/tree/master/android/app/src/main/cpp

В самом проекте библиотеки подключается так:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>

#include "libavutil/opt.h"
#include "libavfilter/avfilter.h"
#include "libavutil/log.h"
#include "libavutil/imgutils.h"

#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include "libavcodec/jni.h"
#include "libavutil/bprint.h"
}

// Extermal Functions Declaration
extern "C"
{
    int ffmpeg_execute(int argc, char** argv);
}
#endif
```

А вызов команды для FFmpeg так:

```
int argc = 5;
string SPath = "storage/emulated/0/Video.mp4
string NewStr = "storage/emulated/0/NewVideoNoSound.mp4
// здесь путь к фидеофайлу может отличаться, запишите на видеокамеру что-ниубдь и пропишите здесь путь к этомй файлу
// FFmpeg поддерживает целую тучу кодеков и форматов, так что это не обязательно должен быть mp4
const char* argv[5] = { "ffmpeg", "-i", SPath.c_str(), "-an", NewStr.c_str() };

// вызов этой функции с такими аргументами это то же самое, как если бы вы запустили в консоли программу ffmpeg.exe с такими параметрами:
// > ffmpeg.exe -i "storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/video.mp4" -an "storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/video_no_audio.mp4"
// параметр -an говорит ffmpeg удалить аудио подток из файла, короче убрать звук и сохранить новый файл в video_no_audio.mp4
ffmpeg_execute(argc, const_cast<char**>(argv));
```

Хочу заметить, что функция main() в ffmpeg.c уже переименована на ffmpeg_execute() в этом коде на GitHub.
Поэтому вы лишь пишете её прототип через extern "c" и вызываете её с нужной вам командой.

Answer (score 0):

Вы изменили имя функции, и теперь нужно перекомпилировать код. Изменение имени и сигнатуры функций требует перекомпиляции самого файла (translation unit) и всех зависимых файлов, потому что меняются таблицы импорта и экспорта в объектных модулях. А вот изменение самого алгоритма внутри функции требует только перекомпиляции одного файла. Короче, вам нужно сбилдить FFmpeg самому. И не факт, что у вас это получится после модификации исходного кода. А поставленной задачи можно добиться, используя саму библиотеку FFmpeg, вместо FFTools.